# WPF: how to save changes in <Image.LayoutTransform> to file?

Tags: image, image-processing

I'm writing an WPF application, using MVVM pattern, which is something like Microsoft Paint clone. I'm present the image in main window and transform it through

```
       <Image x:Name="img" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding Width}"
        Height="{Binding Height}" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" MouseDown="img_MouseDown" MouseUp="img_MouseUp">
            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform  Angle="{Binding RotateAngle}"/>
                    <ScaleTransform  ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY}"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.LayoutTransform>
        </Image>
```

```cs
    private void Save()
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "jpg";
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "JPG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|BMP (*.bmp)|*.bmp";
        saveFileDialog.AddExtension = true;
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(saveFileDialog.FileName) == ".jpg")
            {
                JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(ImageSource));
                using (var filestream = new FileStream(saveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    encoder.Save(filestream);
                }
            }
            else if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(saveFileDialog.FileName) == ".bmp")
            {
                BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(ImageSource));
                using (var filestream = new FileStream(saveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    encoder.Save(filestream);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I know that all my transformations are only stored in XALM file, so my present save function doesn't work. It is possible to get information's about Layouttransorm and make new BitmapImage?